# How to set the router address in OSX Server VPN

Tags: vpn, router, mac-osx-server

I am able to connect to OSX Server (10.9.2) through a (L2TP) VPN tunnel.  However, any other computers in my subnet can not be accessed.

On the client (OSX 10.9.2), the router's IP address is being supplied by PPP (the "Configure IPv4" setting) and it is to the server's IP address and not my router's IP address.  If I change this manually to my router's IP address I can access the other computers in the subnet.

How do I get OSX Server to send the right address to my router?

Comment: By "my subnet", are you talking about the client's subnet or the server's? Also, are the network numbers the same (or overlapping) between the two subnets?